# Throwing OutOfMemoryError exception

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, pdf-reader

In my application, I want to render PDF file in Bitmap. I have found lots of solutions on StackOverflow but nothing worked so far. I have made following changes, `android:largeHeap="true"` and  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

> Here a stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myclasscampus.aspire, PID: 6214
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 434035012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 328MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
at com.aspire.pdfViewer.PDFViewFragment.showPage(PDFViewFragment.java:176)
at com.aspire.pdfViewer.PDFViewFragment.openRenderer(PDFViewFragment.java:154)
at com.aspire.pdfViewer.PDFViewFragment.onCreateView(PDFViewFragment.java:86)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

> Here is my AndroidManifest declaration

```
   <application
        android:name="com.aspire.webserviceConstant.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.calender"
        tools:replace="android:name">
```

> Here is my code which creates bitmap

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void showPage(int index) {
        try {

            if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
                return;
            }

            if (null != currentPage) {
                currentPage.close();
            }

            currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
            releaseBitmap();

            bitmapPDF = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * currentPage.getWidth() / 72,
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * currentPage.getHeight() / 72,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            currentPage.render(bitmapPDF, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imgPdfView.setImageBitmap(bitmapPDF);
            updateUIData();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void releaseBitmap() {
    if (bitmapPDF != null) {
        bitmapPDF.recycle();
        bitmapPDF = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace, not just two lines.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure thing and please check.

Comment: did you also try with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Comment: @ND1010_ I have tried both `true` and `false` and still not working.

Answer (score 4):

```
        bitmapPDF = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * currentPage.getWidth() / 72,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * currentPage.getHeight() / 72,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

This line of code is attempting to allocate 434,035,012 bytes of memory. At 4 bytes per pixel for `ARGB_8888`, that is equivalent to a 10,416 x 10,416 pixel image.

There is no common Android device with a screen resolution anywhere near that size.

Even if you reduce this by quite a bit — say, to more like 1000 x 1000 pixels — you may run into memory problems due to your policy of releasing the `Bitmap`, when combined with limitations in Android's garbage collector.

And, unless *you* created the PDF through Android APIs, it is unlikely that `PdfRenderer` will render it properly anyway. That class exists for print preview, not for rendering arbitrary PDF content.

If you are trying to render arbitrary PDFs, use [other PDF rendering options](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html). If you are trying to perform print preview of PDFs that you created through Android drawing code, and you want to stick with `PdfRenderer`, reduce your resolution and use as few `Bitmap` objects as possible, by reusing previously-allocated ones rather than allocating fresh ones for every page.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and much appreciated. Our main concern is to show PDF within the application. Can you suggest some sort of snippet or any other way to show PDF or anyway to handle this kind of bitmap ?

Comment: @KulsDroid: "Can you suggest some sort of snippet or any other way to show PDF" -- I linked you to [a blog post on the subject](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html). "anyway to handle this kind of bitmap ?" -- I covered this in my answer. Reduce your resolution and use as few `Bitmap` objects as possible, by reusing previously-allocated ones rather than allocating fresh ones for every page.